# JMeter - JUnit Request execute all methods

Tags: junit, jmeter

In JMeter [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) I must choose Test method to define component:

> Test method: The method to test. Required: Yes

How can I execute all methods in class? Isn't a way to define less than X JUnit Requests per method? it seems excessive, is there other way as using Java request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, the purpose of JUnit Request sampler is to measure execution time of a **single** method.

If you are looking for a way to execute all methods in a given class and measure their cumulative execution time there are at least 2 ways:

1. Create as many JUnit Request samplers as many methods you have in your test and put them all under [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)
2. Use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and develop custom code to run your JUnit methods:

   - Using JUnit [Computer](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/Computer.html) class like:

     ```
     import org.junit.runner.Computer
     import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore

     def computer = new Computer()

     def jUnitCore = new JUnitCore()
     jUnitCore.run(computer, Foo.class)
     ```
   - Using [Java Reflection Api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) like:

     ```
     import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.MethodUtils
     import org.junit.Test

     import java.lang.reflect.Method

     Class junitClass = Class.forName('Foo')
     Object t = junitClass.newInstance()
     List<Method> testMethods = MethodUtils.getMethodsListWithAnnotation(junitClass, Test, false, true)
     testMethods.each { method ->
         method.invoke(t, null)
     }
     ```

     Replace `Foo` with the fully qualified name of your JUnit class in both examples in order to get it to work.